# Oauth concepts: what do I gain from Oauth in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security, reactjs, oauth-2.0

**Background** I have some experience implementing Oauth1a and Oauth2 as a client to connect to 'trusted' 3rd party services (twitter, facebook etc), but first time implementing the resource/authorization servers.

I have a basic but not strong understanding of different grant types, and how Oauth attempts to solve the authorization of a user/resource, while protecting user information (login information etc).

**Scenario**: we are creating a client-side application (reactJS) which must submit some basic information to a WordPress site. We control (are the authors of and will host) both react and WordPress on the same server.

We are using WP Rest API: 
http://v2.wp-api.org/

And Oauth server plugin for wordpress
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/

**Question**
The further we get into implementation, the more I ask, what security to I gain at all by adding Oauth in this scenario?

For development and testing, the permissions callback on the POST to our REST endpoint is TRUE (open to any request), and now we are trying to secure it so only our application can submit information to WordPress.

The author of the Oauth server for WordpPress describes for this:

> The access token used to preform a CRUD WP REST API action MUST has been acquired via the password grant type (user credentials).

Which requires embedding the following in the client:

- client ID
- client secret
- wordpress user ID
- wordpress user password

since:

> The access token MUST be assigned to a user id with the correct
>   WordPress capabilities to preform the CRUD action.

Just to get back an access token. 
Note: users do not log in via our react application. The application itself acts as one user in this case.

I must be missing something, exposing the WordPress user name and password seems less secure than skipping Oauth completely, leaving the POST endpoint open, and implementing some kind of submission abuse check, via submission rate, IP or other.

With Oauth2: Someone in control of the client can watch the XHR request and retrieve all information necessary to submit malicious data.

Without Oauth2: someone could use one of many discovery techniques to find our public endpoint and try to submit malicious data.

Things which I may be missing: should I be encrypting/hashing the password, secret, ID etc before embedding in the client?

Should I be separating out our authorization server from the resource server?

Have I missed the point, and Oauth is not a good candidate for this scenario?

Any insight or clarification greatly appreciated.